# Spark cassandra connector Java API with Spark 2.0

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, connector

I am using the datastax spark cassandra connector with Spark 1.6.3.

Is it possible to use the Spark cassandra connector Java API with Spark 2.0+?

I see that the latest version of spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.11 is 1.6.0-M1.

Does someone know about the future of the connector's Java API?

Thanks,

Shai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running Spark 2.0-2.2, you can use Cassandra connector from DataStax https://spark-packages.org/package/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector (which is written in Scala, but you can just consume jar).

Check out the compatibility table in the official repo: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#version-compatibility

Comment: Hi Sergey, thank you for your answer. I am using the Java API with spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10 1.6.0-M2 as a dependency which is the latest. Because of that I am restrained to Spark 1.6.3. I am looking for this jar only in version compatible to Spark 2.0+ so I can upgrade to Spark 2.0+. It seems that the development/support for the Java API is not proceeding. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know the details but it seems like DataStax abandoned `spark-cassandra-connector-java`.

Comment: I think they merged the content of the java jar into the main connector jar. Thanks again!